# Can I restore paid apps from the Software Center after a OS reinstall?

Tags: software-center, paid-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will my once paid for apps be aviable for free after a clean install/format?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32731/will-my-once-paid-for-apps-be-aviable-for-free-after-a-clean-install-format)

Hi all,

I am considering buying an app or two from the Software Center, but I have a few questions before I jump in.  The main issue is that I tend to reinstall Ubuntu after each major release, rather than dist-upgrade.  If I were to buy an app now, and reinstall Ubuntu in 6 months, can I import the app again without paying a second time?

Alon gth